# A command to get buffer content centered in the window

Tags: commands, centering

I'm looking for the built-in command, probably a minor mode, that got my text unstuck from the left border of the window and showed more or less horizontally centered.

The command doesn't modify the text in the buffer, just the view of it.

I got this command while reading the manual, then lost it and now I'm failing to find it back again.

Comment: How about trying?:  https://github.com/joostkremers/writeroom-mode

Comment: I'm looking for that built-in command before trying additional packages

Comment: Built-in commands `center-region`, `center-paragraph`, and `center-line` center lines of text. But they do alter the text in the buffer.